# ¿Como puedo utilizar un método en otra clase y archivo diferente en donde fue creado?

Tags: php, drupal

Cordial saludo para todos.

Acabo de crear un metodo llamado getNodeMetada($nid) dentro de una clase llamada ExternalEventLogTrackService, necesito poder utilizar ese mismo metodo en otra clase que se encuentra en otro archivo, ¿por favor me pueden indicar como se debe hacer?

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ambas clases tienen atributos o funciones en común puedes utilizar la herencia de objetos, ([Documentacion oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php)). Ejemplo:

```
class Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'Foo: ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    public function printPHP()
    {
        echo 'PHP is great.' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class bar extends Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'Bar: ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();
$foo->printItem('baz'); // Salida: 'Foo: baz'
$foo->printPHP();       // Salida: 'PHP is great' 
$bar->printItem('baz'); // Salida: 'Bar: baz'
$bar->printPHP();       // Salida: 'PHP is great'

?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias @jorge-montejo fue de gran ayuda.